# Make multiple scroll views respond together

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I want to make a graph view with scroll views for the center and one for the x axis. Basically if the user scrolls sideways on the center it should cause the x axis scroll view to scroll and stay relative to the center. And vice versa as well. I would want the user to be able to scroll on the x axis scroll view and cause the center to scroll as well.

Attached is an image i have showing the situation.

[image: graph diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Add a delegate to scroll views and implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.xAxisScrollView) {
        CGPoint offset = self.centeredScrollView.contentOffset;
        offset.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
        [self.centeredScrollView setContentOffset:offset];
    }
    else if (scrollView == self.yAxisScrollView) {
        CGPoint offset = self.centeredScrollView.contentOffset;
        offset.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        [self.centeredScrollView setContentOffset:offset];
    }
    else if (scrollView == self.centeredScrollView) {
        [self.xAxisScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)];
        [self.yAxisScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y)];
    }
}
```